# Angular.js setting the value of ng-show by parameter inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Sorry if the title isn't clear, here is what I'm trying to do:

I have multiple signup forms and every one of them has a password field. Now, I want to set some requirements to the passwords, ie. I want to get a password that is longer than 5.

I have:

```
<form name="myForm">

  <!-- some elements -->

  <input type="password" required ng-model="user.password" name="password" ng-minlength="5">
```

and right after that:

```
<div ng-show="myForm.password.$error.minlength">    
    Password is too short.    
</div>

<!-- some other elements -->

</form>
```

I thought I would refactor this error message into a directive, the only problem is that I can't seem to correctly pass the form's name to the directive.

The directive looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('passwordLengthError', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template:'<div ng-show="{{form}}.password.$error.minlength">Password is too short.</div>',
        scope: {
            form: '@'
        }
    };
}]);
```

and I call it like this:

```
<div>
   <password-length-error form="myForm"/>
</div>
```

If I check in Chrome's web inspector, I see that the parameter is there, I see

```
<div ng-show="myForm.password.$error.minlength">
```

however, it doesn't actually work, I don't see the message pop up if the password is shorter than 5 characters.

Is there a way to make this work, or is this not possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` in your isolate scope is trying to evaluate an angular expression.  You are just passing a string, so you can just set the scope variable directly to the attribute value in your directive, without any isolate scope or evaluation of the attribute.

So:

```
scope.form = attrs.form;
```

And the entire directive would be:

```
app.directive('passwordLengthError', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template:'<div ng-show="{{form}}.password.$error.minlength">Password is too short.</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          scope.form = attrs.form  // the attribute is a string, so, YAY
        }
    };
}]);
```

[YOUR DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1VHTiB3Opx7eukcoVyEg?p=preview)